# sedコマンドでn回目に出現する文字を置換する方法

Tags: linux, sed

linuxのsedコマンドでtest.txtの3番目に出現するLinuxをリナックスに置換したいです。

```
test.txt
    Linux
    Linux
    Linux
    Linux
    Linux
```

**私が実行したコマンド**
`sed -i -e 's/Linux/リナックス/3' test.txt`

しかし実際には全ての行のLinuxがリナックスに置換されてしまいます。

```
test.txt
    リナックス
    リナックス
    リナックス
    リナックス
    リナックス
```

どなたか、アドバイスして頂けたら幸いです。

**捕捉**
置換したい対象は行方向に見ていった時、何行目にあるいか分からないが、
n番目(この場合は3番目)に出現するLinuxを置換したいというものです。

**置換対象のパターン**
パターン1
入力

```
test.txt
    android
    Linux
    windows
    windows
    Linux
    macos
    Linux
    android
    Linux
```

出力

```
test.txt
    android
    Linux
    windows
    windows
    Linux
    macos
    リナックス<<3番目に出現したので置換
    android
    Linux
```

パターン2
入力

```
test.txt
    android
    Linux
    windows
    windows
    LinuxLinux
    macos
    Linux
    android
    Linux
```

出力

```
test.txt
    android
    Linux
    windows
    windows
    Linuxリナックス<<3番目に出現したので置換
    macos
    Linux
    android
    Linux
```

以上、よろしくお願いします。

Comment: 置換したいのは
1. 「n行目に出現する"Linux"」
2. 「全ての行において、その行のn番目に出現する"Linux"」
3. 「入力全体を通じて、n番目に出現する"Linux"」
のどれでしょうか。

Comment: ちなみに、質問者さんが実行したコマンドは、「全ての行において、その行の3番目に出現する"Linux"」です。
示された `test.txt` には1行に1つの"Linux"しかありませんから、置換は起こらないはずです（手元で確認しました）。何か操作を間違っているかも知れませんね。

Comment: もう1つ、4. 「"Linux"が含まれる行の内で、n番目にあたる行の"Linux"」という解釈もありますね（Yuki Inoueさんの[回答](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/a/42977/3054)がこれに当ります）。

Comment: すいません。補足いただいていたのを見落としていました。つまり、3の「入力全体を通じて、n番目に出現する"Linux"」という事で大丈夫でしょうか？ （今出ている中では、伽語蓮弥さんの[回答](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/a/42985/3054)がこれに当たります）

Comment: はい、置換の対象は3の「入力全体を通じて、n番目に出現するLinux」という事になります。伝わりずらい文章で申し訳ないです。

Comment: 希望の動作が見えやすいよう、サンプルのテキストを見直してもらった方がよいかなと思います（できれば複数例）。全部同じ行だとコメントが付いている様に意図が伝わりづらいです。

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[rou](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/users/8431/rou)さんの[回答](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/a/42989/25936)を参考にさせていただきました。

```
sed -e '1{; :a; s/Linux/リナックス/3; t; N; ba; }' <test.txt
```

1行目ならコマンドブロックを開始します。
`a`というラベルを設定します。
3番目のLinuxをリナックスに置換します。
置換に成功したら末尾へ移動します。
次の行をパターンスペースへ追加して、`a`というラベルへ移動します。
コマンドブロックを終了します。

Answer (score 3):

3番目(=3行目)だけ置換する場合は以下を実行してみてください。

```
$ cat test.txt | sed -e '3s/Linux/リナックス/'
```

3行目～5行目、などのように範囲指定をする場合は以下になります。

```
$ cat test.txt | sed -e '3,5s/Linux/リナックス/'
```

Answer (score 3):

行をまたいで条件適用させるには、`N` で複数行を同時にパターンスペースに読み込む必要があります。
`sed -i '-e 2,${;p;d;};:a;s/Linux/リナックス/3;t;N;ba' test.txt`

```
1: 2,${
2:   p
3:   d
4: }
5: :a
6: s/Linux/リナックス/3
7: t
8: N
9: ba
```

1～4行目と5～9行目が別ブロックになっています。
アドレス指定により、ファイルの最初の行には5～9行目だけが適用されます。
5～9行目はループになっており、3番目のLinuxの置換処理が成功すれば7行目から抜けます。
見つからなければ8行目でファイルの次行を読み込み、マッチするまで繰り返します。

置換処理が完了した後は、残りの行に1～4行目が適用されます。
入力行を加工せず出力するだけです。

Comment: `sed -i -e '2,${;p;d;};:a;s/Linux/リナックス/3;t;N;ba' test.txt`だと思います。

Comment: @伽語蓮弥 引用符の位置ですか? 昔からの癖ですね。GNU sed はどちらも受け付けるので試してみてください。

Comment: そうだったのですか。こちらの不勉強で申し訳ありません。

Answer (score 1):

sed ではむずかしいので、自分でしたら、 awk をつかうと思います。

```
#!/bin/sh


input() {
    cat <<EOF
Linux
linux
Linux
linux
Linux
linux
Linux
linux
EOF
}

input | awk '/Linux/{c += 1;}
c == 3 {
  gsub("Linux", "hogehoge", $0)
}
{ print $0}
'
```

出力

```
Linux
linux
Linux
linux
hogehoge
linux
Linux
linux
```

Answer (score 1):

GNU版sed(4.x)では、 `-z` オプションを利用できます。
行単位ではなく標準入力全体を対象に処理が可能です。

- 参考 : [sedで複数行にまたがった文字列を置換する方法 | ゲンゾウ用ポストイット](https://genzouw.com/entry/2019/09/09/085746)

```sh
$ cat test.txt
    android
    Linux
    windows
    windows
    Linux
    macos
    Linux
    android
    Linux

$ sed -z 's/Linux/リナックス/3' < test.txt
    android
    Linux
    windows
    windows
    Linux
    macos
    リナックス
    android
    Linux
```

いかがでしょうか？